# How to remove phrases in a column and let just the number?

Tags: python

The df it is like that:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| FUNCIONARIOS | 30140 |
| BURITIS | 30140 |
| 30431 | 30145 |
| 35481 | 54585 |

and i need that:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
|  | 30140 |
|  | 30140 |
| 30431 | 30145 |
| 35481 | 54585 |

Comment: It is not entirely clear whether in this case it could be that the column contains numbers mixed with letters

Comment: there is no number mixed with letters.

Comment: Does column A actually contain **numbers**? Or does it contain strings that use all digit symbols? What result do you get if you check the `dtype` of the column? What result do you get if you extract an individual value from the column, and check its `type`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the question literally, then [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) will help you:

```py
df["Column A"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Column A"], errors='coerce')
```